# Using multiple @yields with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have worked with Laravel before and have some applications that utilize multiple @yields inside of the template files, probably not best practice but I'm still learning a bunch.

I recently started a fresh installation to begin a new project and I'm trying to get a navbar and home page configured together using the templating engine and it looks like such:

master.blade.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    @yield('content2')
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <h1>Test</h1>
@endsection
```

test.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content2')
    <h1>Test2</h1>
@endsection
```

The issue that I'm running into is that only the `@yield('content')` works the other one doesn't appear to be read at all, I've done this in the past but I'm not sure what might be causing it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could use `@section('sec_name') @show` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my tests, your example demo in the question works fine without any issues. [Template inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#defining-a-layout).

Nonetheless, you may try making use of the "modern" anonymous components.

[Anonymous Components](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#anonymous-components)

> Similar to inline components, anonymous components provide a mechanism
> for managing a component via a single file. However, anonymous
> components utilize a single view file and have no associated class. To
> define an anonymous component, you only need to place a Blade template
> within your `resources/views/components` directory.

**resources/views/components/layouts/master.blade.php**

```php
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>{{ $title ?? 'Test' }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ $content ?? '' }}
        {{ $content2 ?? '' }}
    </body>
</html>
```

**resources/views/welcome.blade.php**

```
<x-layouts.master>

    <x-slot name="title">
        Test
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="content">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </x-slot>

</x-layouts.master>
```

**resources/views/test.blade.php**

```
<x-layouts.master>

    <x-slot name="title">
        Test2
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="content2">
        <h1>Test2</h1>
    </x-slot>

</x-layouts.master>
```

Comment: Gotcha so this looks like it may just be a situation with my local installation.  That's so odd, but I have seen stranger things happen.  So when using anonymous components it's reading what you name them in the ```x-slot name=""``` sections and then just treats them like variables?  I'm just asking to understand if I'm getting that properly :D

Comment: @Recypher You're correct with your understanding of anonymous components. The *old fashion way* you used in your question still works up to now, I just don't understand why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Recypher If the answer helped you resolve your issue, you may [mark it as the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow).

Comment: Sorry, still new to this, thanks for the hlep!

Comment: I will say it is strange that I tested it on two different servers and got the same issue, but I'm always willing to try new things out.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass empty string as default value for yield like so :

```
@yield('content2' , '')
```